# Guidelines for deciding when some set of artifacts should be packed into a NuGet package

Tags: nuget, packaging, nuget-package, package-managers

While technically it is possible to create NuGet packages from an arbitrary set of artifacts, are there some rules/industry standards that can help decide when it makes sense to create a NuGet package?

While release and versioning are some obvious factors (If a component releases on its own cadence, if *may* be a good candidate for release as a NuGet package), are there other such deciding factors that justify creation and distribution as a NuGet package?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.nuget.org/ has docs about NuGet packages, NuGet package manager and its ecosystem. It may give you some idea about when/how to use NuGet.